# How to start calculating indicator on specific number of hours minutes or bars back?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

i am trying to create script which calculates and shows indicator for just last several hours or bars. Right now, I am working with timestamp - telling script where it should start or with specific input of bar index. But problem with timestamp is that you need to set it every day to see the indicator just for last 1 or 2 days. And problem with bar index is, that it is different for premium users (20k bars), and it also varies for different instruments. The best way would be to set value of barindex to start calculating on every intrument type (forex, futures, stocks) and timeframe (if youd like to see last 2 days, it is different amount of bars for 1 minute timeframe, then for 4 hours). But that will overfill user input window. Is there any other solution, that would be more convenient? Like specifying hours or days back or something?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator("Test")
t = input.int(2, "No of days")

if timenow - t*24*60*60*1000 <= time
    // do my logic
    ...
...
```